# CSS/HTML Button in PayPal

Tags: html

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="76BSEEPTFTS3KN">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.yorsitename.com/images/cartbutton.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This is code for image button. How can I use for CSS/HTML button? Paypal has their buttons and a image button you created yourself.

Answer (score 2):

for some reason, if you change the `<input type="image">` element to `<input type="button">` the form doesn't submit. Instead, change it to `<input type="submit">`.

example:

```
<input type="image" src="http://www.yorsitename.com/images/cartbutton.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

change to

```
<input type="submit" class="css here" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" value="Custom Button Text Here">
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Change `<input type="image"` to `<input type="button"`